# How can I align controls vertically in Windows Forms apps?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, alignment, vertical-alignment, windows-forms-designer

I have several paired label/textbox and label/combobox controls on a form. Getting them aligned horizontally is not a problem, but it's kind of a pain getting them vertically aligned with an even amount of vertical spacing / Y axis.

In the olden days with Delphi this was a breeze - you highlight all the controls, select an item from a menu, and voila!

Is there something similar in Visual Studio (2012 Ultimate)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by going to Format in main menu and then align, so you can choose any type of alignment.

Comment: Can you please comment it more?